# mysql syntax error in php code

Tags: php, mysql

Been a while since I've done any database work, trying to get back into it....

The error:

> Error updating database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'select id from FKCust where id ='1','3333',
>   '1364186198','1')' at line 1

The code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customerID, purchaseNo, dateCreated, statusID) VALUES (select id from FKCust where id ='$customerId','$purchaseOrder', '$dateEntered','1')";
```

If you need the database structure I will post it as well. Just leave a comment.

Comment: You're giving 4 column names but select 1 column in the VALUES part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customerID, purchaseNo, dateCreated, statusID) 
VALUES ((select id from FKCust where id ='$customerId'),
'$purchaseOrder', '$dateEntered','1')";
```

Comment: Ah I forgot the bracket, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customerID, purchaseNo, dateCreated, statusID)
        VALUES (select id, '$purchaseOrder', '$dateEntered','1'
                  from FKCust
                 where id = $customerId
               )";
```

Just a simple syntax error, it happens to us all.

**edit**: I'm sure your customerID column is an INT, not a CHAR, *right*? I've removed those quotes. They'll break your indexes, which I'm *sure* you've created, right?

Comment: You are correct, however customerID is the only foreign key the others are from orders.

Answer (score 1):

***Just Try With The Following :***

```
<?php
$selectCust = mysql_query("select `id` from `FKCust` where `id` ='".$customerId."'") or die(mysql_error());
$resultCust = mysql_fetch_array($selectCust);
$getCustID  = $resultCust['id'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`customerID`,`purchaseNo`,`dateCreated`,`statusID`) VALUES ('".$getCustID."','".$purchaseOrder."', '".$dateEntered."','1')";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Why do two round trips to the database when one is sufficient?

Comment: I'm just explaining the detailed query to the user to understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

While I can see it's solved, it's interesting why do you have a different ID for the customer in the *customer* and the *orders* tables?  Why use a *FKCust* table to do the linking instead of a simple foreign key in the *orders*?  It seems to me that's the reason you need all sorts of weird handling in the first place; otherwise it'd be just a straight insert.

And now you can't simply select the data (eg orders for a customer) either, because matching the rows will be a pain in the arse.

Or am I missing something?